# Display two views in a row or column depending on orientation using AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

A fairly simple question but I'm unable to work it out for myself:

Given the layout displayed below I want the two container to maintain their size (270x270 points) but display them in a row for landscape orientation. What constraints do I need? I tried using the left / right margin constraints and fixed size for both of them but it does not work.

[image: Screenshot from InterfaceBuilder]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try height and width for both of them. Top and left for the top box. Bottom and Right for the bottom box.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that merely by using a single set of constraints. You'll want to implement `updateViewConstraints` and *replace* the constraints with a different set as needed. What I do is prepare both sets of constraints beforehand and keep them as instance variables, and swap them in and out as the device rotates:

```
-(void)updateViewConstraints {
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.landscapeConstraints];
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.portraitConstraints];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))
        [self.view addConstraints:self.landscapeConstraints];
    else
        [self.view addConstraints:self.portraitConstraints];
    [super updateViewConstraints];
}
```

For an actual example, see https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p255rotationChangesInterface/ch19p593rotationChangesInterface/ViewController.m

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this will be helpful when using layout for a more complex interface :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible to do using only the storyboard unless you use a collection view. A collection view would automatically wrap the second cell if it didn't fit horizontally. If you don't want to use a collection view then you will need to manually modify the constraints at runtime depending on the orientation.

If you do choose to manually modify constraints, I recommend the excellent [Masonry](https://github.com/cloudkite/Masonry) library.

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick answer ... CollectionView is overkill for this as they are only two views to display. I will look into modifying the constraints in code (maybe using Masonry) when the orientation changes :)